# Non-Invocable Member 'String.Length' cannot be used like a method

Tags: c#

I am trying to get a script component to work for an HRIS Package that I am working on.
I am getting a Non-Invocable error. I am not familiar with C# so I am not sure how to correct this. I am working with a fried that altered a code that was given to me previously by another STO member.

The .Length(); is what is causing the conflict, as is the "i"'s at the end in the "for" statement.

The altered code is below.

```
/* Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services Script Component
*  Write scripts using Microsoft Visual C# 2008.
*  ScriptMain is the entry point class of the script.*/

using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

[Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.SSISScriptComponentEntryPointAttribute]
public class ScriptMain : UserComponent
{

public override void PreExecute()
{
    base.PreExecute();
    /*
      Add your code here for preprocessing or remove if not needed
    */
}

public override void PostExecute()
{
    base.PostExecute();
    /*
      Add your code here for postprocessing or remove if not needed
      You can set read/write variables here, for example:
      Variables.MyIntVar = 100
    */
}

public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
{
    const string pFirstName = @"^[A-Z]([-']?[a-z]+)*";
    const string pSuffix = @"((Jr|Sr|I|V|X)( ?))+";
    const string pInitial = @"(?<=\s)[A-Z](?=\s)";
    const string pLastName = @"(?!(?:Jr|Sr|I|V|X|^))([A-Z][-'\s]?[a-z]+)";

    string fullName = Row.Name.ToString();
    string firstName = Regex.Match(fullName, pFirstName).Value;
    string suffix = Regex.Match(fullName, pSuffix).Value;
    string initial = Regex.Match(fullName, pInitial).Value;
    string lastName = Regex.Match(fullName, pLastName).Value;

    /*
     * 20130708 - Edited by Armando Allison
     * 
     * 
     * 1. Get the length of the entire full name
     * 2. Get the firstName length value
     * 3. Get the initial length value
     * 4. Get the suffix length value
     * 5. Get the lastName length value
     * 
     * 
     */


    int length_full = fullName.Length();     //length of fullName
    int length_first = firstName.Length();    //length of the firstName
    int length_suffix = suffix.Length();   //length of the suffix
    int length_initial = initial.Length();  // length of the initial
    int length_lastName = lastName.Length(); //length of the lastName

    int compare_length = 0;
    compare_length = length_full - (length_first - length_initial - length_suffix); //      if it pulled the data correctly, lastName length should equal compare_length


    if (length_lastName == compare_length)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(initial))
            lastName += " " + initial;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(suffix))
            lastName += " " + suffix;

        Row.FirstName = firstName;
        Row.LastName = lastName;

    }
    else
    {
        // if the lastName doesnt match the compare_length
        // you will have to do some more editing.

        // 1. put entire full name into a string array
        // 2. remove all the suffix, initial, and firstName
        // 3. then output the entire lastName in a for loop with the remaining full name array 
        //    remove to remove the other parts of the array that is not needed
        // Pseudo code

        char[] entire_name;
        entire_name = new char[length_full];
        entire_name = fullName.ToCharArray(0, length_full);
        for (i = compare_length; i < length_full - 1; i++)
        {
            lastName = (String)entire_name[i];
        }
        // loop entire array to include the entire full name
        // next remove the parts of the array that is not needed
        // then output just the last name with another for loop




    }



}

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the **Length** is a property of the type **string** so remove the paranthesis.
Just call :

```
suffix.Length;
```

also

```
for(int i = compare_length; i < length_full - 1; i++)
{
     //Do something
}
```

because you have to define i as an int inside the loop.

Plus,

`lastName = (String)entire_name[i];` is wrong

use :

```
lastName = entire_name[i].ToString();
```

Comment: This looks like it fixed the errors. Thank you for all of the info. I will share this with my friend that was helping me write this up.

Comment: After i fixed the errors I ran the package. It created the FirstName and LastName columns but it did not insert any data. All the rows for those two columns were blank. Any ideas?

Comment: Whats funny is that the accepted answer got less votes than all the rest of the answers, not fair at all for a guy with 256 rep like me :D

Comment: I liked your answer because of the detail, it answered both of my questions. I actually liked several of the answers but I learned I can only choose 1. I am new to this site and just learned of the votes and answer acceptions the other day. Hopefully in time I will work up my rep and be as knowledgeable as the rest of you. Thank you again for the answer. ;)

Comment: This issue is fixed. However, another has appeared. If you have insight please visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17556005/script-component-fields-not-populating hopefully you were not the one to give me the -1, lol.

Comment: @BrianD.Brubaker to be honest i can't be much of a help with this new issue, though i wish you goodluck :)

Answer (score 11):

`Length()` is not a method, it's a property.  Just use `Length` without the parentheses.

Comment: That worked great, thank you for the input. I'm just delving into the possibilities of what SQL is capable of. This is the first time i have used C#. What about the "i"'s at the end? any idea why it tells me "the name 'i' does not exist in the current context".

Comment: You need to declare `i` before using it, e.g.  `for(int i = 0; i < ...;i++)`

Answer (score 5):

The compilation error seems very clear to me. This:

```
int length_full = fullName.Length();
```

should be:

```
int length_full = fullName.Length;
```

... and likewise for your other lines. This is because [`String.Length`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.length.aspx) is a property, not a method.

Aside from fixing your code, you should look at the compilation error again and try to work out why you found it confusing - that may help you to find out bits of C# which you should become more familiar with. I would strongly advise you to become more familiar with the basics of C# *before* you mess too much with other things such as databases - it'll make it a lot easier to diagnose any problems later on.

Comment: Thank you for the advise. I wish it was that easy. I have taken a few SQL Classes but nothing with C# in it. Kind of got thrust into this role.

Comment: @BrianD.Brubaker: That doesn't mean you can't put the rest on pause, learn the basics of C#, and then come back to it...

Answer (score 3):

[`Length` is a property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.length.aspx), not a method, you can omit the `()`:

```
int length_full = fullName.Length;
```

Answer (score 3):

`Length` is a property, not a function.  Just remove the parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

the "i" at the end of the for loop issue should be able to be fixed by replacing your loop declaration with

```
for(int i = compare_length; i < length_full - 1; i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use only Length shown below not Length() its not method.

```
fullName.Length;
```